# Swift - declare empty collection without data type?

Tags: swift, collections, empty-list

Can you declare an empty collection (array, set, dictionary) in Swift without knowing its data type? I'm following the 100 days of Swift site, but it doesn't mention how you can declare an empty collection. I'm pretty sure there will be cases where you don't know what data type you want to fill into this collection right?

For example if I want to define an empty dictionary:

```
var emptyDictionary = [String: String]()
```

But if I change it to

```
var emptyDictionary = [Any: Any]()
```

It will throw an error. Same thing goes for arrays and sets.

Comment: Well, you _could_ use `NSMutableDictionary`, but that's not very swifty.

Comment: You will not get an error if you declare an array to be [Any] but more importantly why would you need to declare an array  without a type?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays with type `Any` do compile; for example

```
let array = [Any]()
```

compiles without errors. However, the keys for the dictionary have to conform to `Hashable` due to the nature of the structure. Therefore, by making the key `Hashable`, you can create a dictionary with 'any' type.

```
struct Foo<T: Hashable> {
    let dict = [T: Any]()
}
```

However, it does not make much sense to do so to use `Any` for the key. Using something like

```
let dict = [String: Any]()
```

would work perfectly fine for most cases where you don't know the datatype of the value or have varying datatypes.